# Send data outside the factory real time using angularjs interceptor

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, interceptor

I want to solve on how to use `$scope.time` to my html.
I want to show in UI the time the last http request but gives me an error.
I cant use `$scope`.

I Have these codes:

```
module.factory('timestamp', [function ($scope) { 
var time = {
    request: function (config) {

        $scope.time = new Date().getTime(); //wanted to show in UI realtime
        return config;
    }
    //,response: function (response) {
    //    response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
    //    return response;
    //}
};
return time;}];
```

Config:

```
module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('timestamp');}
```

Answer (score 0):

try return $scope.time or get the time in any variable return that instead of config
and try to access it

```
module.factory('timestamp', [function ($scope) { 
var time = {
    request: function (config) {

       config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        return config;
    },
    response: function(response) {
        response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        return response;
    }

};
return time;}];
```

Controller

```
module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('timestamp');}
```

Comment: this will error in `return config` , config must be return so that http request will push through

Comment: Yea i saw this also [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/).

The problem is how to access from other controller.

Comment: I still cant access the config/response in my main controller

`module.controller('MainController', function ($scope,timestamp){
console.log(timestamp.config);
});`

Comment: console.log(timestamp.request(config));
console.log(timestamp.request());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190418/discussion-between-gowtham-rajan-and-francis-lim).

Comment: module.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'timestamp', function($scope, timestamp) {
  // Rest of controller code;
}]);